# Understanding cyclic System.gc() calls in Java 8 / Wildfly 10 application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, wildfly

Please help me to understand the need of cyclic `System.gc()` calls in my Wildfly 10 application.

**Problem description**

My application gets slower and slower over the course of an hour. As you can see in the picture, the response times improve immediately after garbage collection from 1000ms to about 200ms. Then the response times rise again until the next GC comes.
[image: Response time]

Similar behavior shows the CPU usage.

[image]

**What is known?**

I know that garbage collection is triggered by `sun.misc.GC` class. Heap Dump also contains the class as well as the Damon thread that excutes the cyclic `System.gc()` calls.
[image: HeapDump]

The analysis has shown that the remote service is very fast. This means that the high response times caused by a too long connection establishment. 
Obviously, the connection lasts longer and longer due to the old "dead" remote objects.

[image: EJB3-Stateless-Beans]

**What I don't understand?**

I know that the GC.java class triggers a **full garbage collection** to remove the unneeded remote objects. However, I do not understand why these remote objects need to be removed this way. (Is it because these objects survives too often the minor GC?)

As far as I know, the client tells the server that the remote object is no longer used - (DGC) Distributed Garbage Collection. 
The server knows, thanks to DGC, that a remote object is no longer used.

**So my questions are...**

1. Why do we need a Full GC to remove the old Remote Objects?
2. Why are the old remote objects slowing down my application?

**UPDATE**

Communication with jboss 4 clients causes the GC cycles. 
JVP start parameters are:

```
-Xms4g
-Xmx8g
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
```

Comment: You should post GC logs and JVM options used

Comment: If a client disconnects unexpectedly, or the client code has a bug where it fails to notify the server it no longer needs a component, a resource might never be cleaned up in a graceful manner but hopefully a full GC will release it. To look at why more GC is used, you need to see how the sizes of the regions have changed. e.g. has the tenured space started to fill up, or is the young space much smaller/larger.